# Selenium WebDriver returning error when trying to compare two strings

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to compare two values and I wrote the following code that is returning the error below. I'm not a Java Developer and so I do not know how to solve this issue. I tried to find something on the Internet but I couldn't. I appreciate your help.

```
// import statements begin for selenium imports

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

//import statements end for selenium imports


String formulaTotalQuantity = handl.getExportedValue(“E_CPE_FORMULA__TOTAL_QUANTITY_”);
String orderQuantity = handl.getExportedValue(“E_ORDER_QUANTITY”);

if(orderQuantity.equals(formulaTotalQuantity)){
   System.out.println("Pass");
}
  else {
      System.out.println("Fail");
}
```

This is the error I am getting when I try to activate the code:

`ERROR : illegal character: '\ufffd'/n`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. It was related to the fact that I was using the quotation mark in the wrong manner. I changed it and then the error is gone.